Nesting HLOOKUP and MATCH functions to report a value based on closest prior date
I'm making a spreadsheet to convert values based on set exchange rates in Excel for MS 365 v. 2403.
On a Summary worksheet I have Transaction Date and USD Exchange Rate, where the later is pulled from the Exchange Rate Tracker Worksheet.
Worksheet 1: Summary



Transaction Date
USD Exchange Rate




Cell A2
Cell B2


Cell A3
Cell B3



On the Exchange Rate Tracker sheet I have the set date and the set exchnage rates for different currencies (manually entered, not using the Excel functions).
Worksheet 2: Exchange Rate Tracker



Date
01-May-2022




USD
Cell B2


CAD
Cell B3


Euro
Cell B4


Yen
Cell B5



I want to pull the exchange rate from Worksheet 2 row 2 based on the nearest prior date given in Worksheet 2 row 1 and have it reported into Worksheet 1 column B.
Example Data:
Worksheet 1: Summary



Transaction Date
USD Exchange Rate




27-May-2024
Cell B2


06-Jun-2021
Cell B3



Worksheet 2: Exchange Rate Tracker



Date
08-Dec-2019
01-May-2022




USD
1
5


CAD
2
6


Euro
3
7


Yen
4
8



I'm trying to nest a HLOOKUP and MATCH function, however I'm having errors with the basic match function using dates as formatted.
Using
=(MATCH('Summary'!$A5,'Exchange Rate Tracker'!$B$1:$ZZ$1,1))
I'm getting 01-Jan-1900 ("date 0" in Excel). Was thinking this may be because the entirety of Exchnage Rate Tracker Row 1 isn't completed with dates, but narrowing the date doesn't change the response.
I would like something like
=HLOOKUP(MATCH('Summary'!$A5,'Exchange Rate Tracker'!$B$1:$ZZ$1,1),'Exchange Rate Tracker'!$B$1:$ZZ$500,2)
Which currently gives an #N/A error.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This formula uses data from the same sheet. Specify the ranges with sheet names as desired.
=INDEX(A2:C5,,MATCH(B11,A1:C1,1))

With formatting as in the question:
=INDEX(A$2:C$2,,MATCH(D12,$A$1:$C$1,1))  and drag down.


With XMATCH and INDEX
Here's a suggestion using dynamic ranges and named functions.
Since the ranges (dynamically) include rows and columns with data, chances of getting #N/A are reduced.
Hope you have time to check these.

Named functions can be used from any sheet and also will be carried over when you copy a sheet to a new workbook.
With helper functions and named ranges, we use the following dynamic array formula to lookup (no need to fill down):
=lookup_tracked_rate("USD",INDEX(_summary,0,1))

In order to keep the ranges dynamically updated when there is a change, we can use the volatile function RAND in the header like this:
=IF(RAND()*0,"","Transaction Date")

Named ranges and functions (please adjust these to match your ranges):

_rate_tracker   
='SO-78540058'!$F$1:$H$5

_summary    
=OFFSET('SO-78540058'!$A$2,0,0,COUNTA('SO-78540058'!$A$2:'SO-78540058'!$A$200),2)

_tracker_col    
=LAMBDA(date, XMATCH(date,INDEX(_rate_tracker,1,0),-1))

_tracker_row    
=LAMBDA(symbol, XMATCH(symbol,INDEX(_rate_tracker,0,1),0))

lookup_tracked_rate 
=LAMBDA(_symbol,_date, INDEX(_rate_tracker,_tracker_row(_symbol),_tracker_col(_date)))



Using Tables
When matching dates in the rates table, convert these to date values as the column headers are of type text type.
lookup_tracked_rate 
=LAMBDA(_symbol,_date, INDEX(_rate_tracker,_tracker_row(_symbol),_tracker_col(_date)))


tracked_rate    
=LAMBDA(_symbol,_date, FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(tblTrackedRates,_rate_col(_date)),tblTrackedRates[Symbol]=_symbol))


tracked_rate_col    
=LAMBDA(date, XMATCH(date,DATEVALUE(tblTrackedRates[#Headers]),-1))

I have not included any error checking.

